# In Arduino, what are the raw values for the HIGH, LOW, INPUT, and OUTPUT

Tags: arduino

What are the actual values for HIGH, LOW, INPUT, and OUTPUT?
These are used in functions like pinMode() and digitalWrite().

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These might be of use to you:

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Constants

[Arduino HIGH LOW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12432955/arduino-high-low)

```
#define HIGH 0x1
#define LOW  0x0

#define INPUT 0x0
#define OUTPUT 0x1

#define true 0x1
#define false 0x0
```

So basically they are booleans since C/C++ represents true as `0x1` and false as `0x0`

Comment: i am trying to port the sample blink program to AVR-C in atmel studio. Do you have any idea how to still use the arduino functions while writing the program?

Comment: I haven't messed around with amt. studio, but I'm sure someone else has implemented blink in AVR-C so the answers are out there.